# What requirements does the Artificer's Magic Item Savant feature ignore?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, artificer, attunement

The [Artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer)'s [Magic Item Savant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#MagicItemSavant-1134349) feature (E:RftLW, p. 58; WGtE, p. 180) states:

> [...] You ignore all class, race, spell, and level requirements on attuning to or using magic items.

Class and race requirements are relatively intuitive, additionally, since an Artificer is able to cast spells they can already attune to items that require you to be a spellcaster. But there's still some questions:

- Can they use a spell scroll of a spell not on their spell list? Is this one of the four requirements ignored?
- What are level and spell requirements; what are some examples?

Comment: Related: [How does an artificer's Magic Item Savant feature interact with spell scrolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/161327/33569), [Do an Artificer's Magic Item Savant feature and a multiclassed Thief Rogue's Use Magic Device feature let them benefit from a Rod of the Pact Keeper?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163204/33569), [Do an Artificer's Magic Item Savant feature and a Thief Rogue's Use Magic Device feature let them benefit from a Holy Avenger's 30-foot aura?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163203/33569)

Answer (score 3):

**Yes to both.**
For number one, I think it's intended to refer to a) the ability to cast spells in the first place and b)to spellcasting class, as I don't believe there are any magic items which require you to be able to cast a *specific* spell, only that require you to be able to cast spells, and, more specifically, belong to the class that the item requires.
Regarding number two, the easiest example is a Holy Avenger(which requires you to be a paladin to attune to it in the first place):

> While you hold the drawn sword, it creates an aura in a 10-foot radius around you. You and all creatures friendly to you in the aura have advantage on saving throws against spells and other magical effects. If you have 17 or more levels in the paladin class, the radius of the aura increases to 30 feet.

The artificer feature should allow you to ignore both of those requirements.
As a side note, this feature allows you to use a few magic items that are normally fairly locked down, namely a Mind Lash, which requires attunement by an illithid.

Comment: [Jeremy Crawford recently responded to a tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1227661727761719296) to confirm that the artificer's Magic Item Savant allows artificers to ignore the attunement requirement on magic items that can only be attuned to by a creature with a certain dragonmark (e.g. *finder's goggles*), since dragonmarks are mechanically subraces. (It looks like the same is true of the [Thief rogue](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Thief)'s Use Magic Item feature.) Might be worth mentioning/addressing in your answer.