# Are there any examples of "level requirements" that can be ignored with Use Magic Device?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, rogue, thief

The Thief Rogue's 13th level feature allows them to ignore requirements on the use of magic items:

> **Use Magic Device.** By 13th level, you have learned enough about the workings of magic that you can improvise the use of items even when they are not intended for you. You ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of magic items.

I've found examples of items that have class requirements (e.g. a Rod of the Pact Keeper) and of items that have race requirements (e.g. a Moonblade). However, I couldn't find any examples of items that have level-based requirements on their use.

**Are there any, or is this a redundant (/future-proofing) clause in the feature?**

Items from any published 5th edition material would be welcome as answers; if the only examples are in UA that would be useful information as well.

Comment: I felt this was a duplicate, but if not these are certainly related: "[What requirements does the Artificer's Magic Item Savant feature ignore?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/161329)" and "[Do an Artificer's Magic Item Savant feature and a Thief Rogue's Use Magic Device feature let them benefit from a Holy Avenger's 30-foot aura?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163203)" and "[Do an Artificer's Magic Item Savant feature and a multiclassed Thief Rogue's Use Magic Device allow them to benefit from a Rod of the Pact Keeper?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/163204)"

Comment: Given that they're asking about 2 separate features, they're not quite duplicates, though they are similar/related. In particular, the linked question is a bit broader than this one; it's about all the requirements that the artificer's Magic Item Savant feature ignores, whereas this one is just about "level" requirements. The linked question also asks about Magic Item Savant ignoring "spell" requirements, which the Thief rogue's Use Magic Device feature doesn't say it does.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth noting that the artificer has the same wording listed in its class description of similar ability. Mainly important because it was released much later so at the very least, it is unlikely to simply be an error.

> You ignore all class, race, spell, and level requirements on attuning to or using a magic item.

However as for Actual applications: One case I can find that *might* relate to it is  spell scrolls:

> If the spell is on your class’s spell list but of a higher level than you can normally cast, you must make an ability check using your spellcasting ability to determine whether you cast it successfully. The DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a failed check, the spell disappears from the scroll with no other effect.

The reason I mention might, is that it doesn't directly reference character level but rather spell levels, which are attained at higher levels.

Unfortunately [There isn't a solid answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89098/how-can-a-rogue-use-use-magic-device-to-cast-spells-from-scrolls) on if rogues are meant to be able to use spell scrolls.

Another situation in which character level *might* be applicable is the Holy Avenger

> While you hold the drawn sword, it creates an aura in a 10-foot radius around you. You and all creatures friendly to you in the aura have advantage on saving throws against spells and other magical effects. **If you have 17 or more levels in the paladin class, the radius of the aura increases to 30 feet.**

Again, this doesn't say something which is verbatim in the class feature. However, clearly having a higher class level affects USING this magic item. Remember the description mentions "requirements on the use of magic items." However, this requirement isn't a requirement for use, but rather more of a requirement for additional features.

In conclusion: If you interpret the rules broadly, this part of the class feature will enable greater use of some magical items.

However, it appears there are currently no direct requirements related to levels on magical item use in official published 5e material. The DMG even specifically suggests avoiding adding attunement rules. Another note is that monsters (or npcs) typically do not have levels (spellcasters are often specified however) so any magic item with a character level requirement would create a conflict in usage between NPCs and PCs.

Answer (score 3):

#### The Sword of Zariel is a possible candidate.

It is unclear if the wording of **Use Magic Device** changes how destroying the [Sword of Zariel](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/sword-of-zariel) works, so it will be up to the DM, but it is still worth mentioning in response to this question.

From *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*, concerning the destruction of the Sword of Zariel:

> The sword is also destroyed if it’s used to shatter the Companion (see “Shattering the Companion”), unless the blade is wielded by an angel of challenge rating 15 or higher, or a good-aligned cleric or paladin of at least 10th level.

Again, it is unclear of **Use Magic Device** would affect this, but this is a class and level requirement that is placed on a particular use of the Sword of Zariel that **Use Magic Device** may provide a workaround for.