# Do an Artificer's Magic Item Savant feature and a multiclassed Thief Rogue's Use Magic Device feature let them benefit from a Rod of the Pact Keeper?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, artificer

The [Artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer)'s [*Magic Item Savant*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#MagicItemSavant-1134349) feature (E:RftLW, p. 58; WGtE, p. 180) states the following:

> At 14th level, your skill with magic items deepens more:
>
> - [...]
> - You ignore all class, race, spell, and level requirements on attuning
>     to or using a magic item.

The [Thief Rogue](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#Thief)'s [*Use Magic Device*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#UseMagicDevice-367) feature (PHB, p. 97) states the following:

> By 13th level, you have learned enough about the workings of magic that you can improvise the use of items even when they are not intended for you. You ignore all class, race, and level requirements on the use of magic items.

The description of the [Rod of the Pact Keeper](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/rod-of-the-pact-keeper) (DMG, p. 197) states the following:

> While holding this rod, you gain a +1 bonus to spell attack rolls and to the saving throw DCs of your warlock spells.
>
> In addition, you can regain one warlock spell slot as an action while holding the rod. You can't use this property again until you finish a long rest.

Since these features allow an Artificer or a multiclassed Thief Rogue to ignore "class" requirements when using a Rod of the Pact Keeper, would they ignore all instances of "Warlock" in the text and benefit from the general bonus to spell attack rolls and saving throw DCs, and be able to regain one spell slot?

Related questions:

1. [What requirements does the Artificer's Magic Item Savant feature ignore?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/161329/what-requirements-does-the-artificers-magic-item-savant-feature-ignore)
2. [Does an Artificer's Magic Item Savant and a Thief Rogue's Use Magic Device allow them to benefit from a Holy Avenger's 30-foot aura?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163203/does-an-artificers-magic-item-savant-and-a-thief-rogues-use-magic-device-allow)

Answer (score 6):

### Short answer, no

The item clearly states that it's benefits are for Warlock abilities. The attunement requirement in this case is simply because other classes have no use for it, so it doesn't make sense for them to be able to attune to it. When it says that it gives a bonus to attacks an DCs of Warlock spells, that means spells learned through warlock levels, and ditto for the spell slots. In other words, you can technically benefit from it, but it only targets a warlock;s spells and spell slots, so since you aren't a warlock, you get no real benefit from it.

Now, you might argue that the warlock part of even that could be ignored, but I'd argue otherwise. In this case, it does not seem to be used as a **requirement**. Something benefiting a certain kind of effect or feature **is not generally a requirement**. The key difference in this case I would have to say is the difference between a requirement for something to gain an effect from something else, versus the requirement to have that effect available in the first place.

Comment: But both features clearly state that you ignore "class" requirements, and that could be taken as ignoring "Warlock" in the text of the item. It's similar to how one may (or may not) be able to benefit from a Holy Avenger's 30-foot aura. Are you implying that an Artificer or Thief Rogue could never benefit from the 30-foot aura?

Comment: I agree with this answer, and also with the addendum: they wouldn't benefit from the 30ft aura from a Holy Avenger

Comment: Since you don't think they can benefit from either, do you think an Artificer or Thief Rogue be able to use a Wheel of Wind and Water?

Comment: Technically it is possible (via feat) to have access to warlock spells without any warlock class levels.  I believe in that case, the thief rogue or artificer would be able to use a Rod of the Pact Keeper to buff their feat-derived warlock spells, while, say, a rogue with that feat would not.

Answer (score 6):

## The answer is no with a but

The Rogue and Artificer abilities allow you to ignore the prerequisites for the item attunement. This allows you to attune to the Rod but it would do you no good. The class features does not ignore or alter the magic item abilities. The abilities of the rod give a higher DC and spell attack bonus to **Warlock** spells. Unless you have Warlock spells from a *multiclass* or the *magic initiate feat* this would do you no good. The other benefit of the rod gives you another **Warlock** spell slot once per long rest. Unless you have a multiclass with Warlock this benefit does nothing for you.

You can attune to the item but without Warlock spell slots or spells, this item will do nothing but take up an attunement.